# Free libraries for adding some eye candy to WinForm apps?

Tags: winforms

I want to spice up some gray WinForm apps. Any recommendations for free WinForm libraries.

I have seen AquaButtons at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/aquabutton.aspx

I am looking for more versatile free libraries which add similar buttons, color gradients to panes, title bars, toolbars.. etc.

Also if you know of sample apps on the web for nice looking, maybe WPF'ish, WinForm apps which I can get some ideas from, that would be great. (I do not plan to put WPF controls in the WinForm apps)

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net/361331#361331

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/) controls are pretty good

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a old post-ill awnser anyways :)

So as of right now there are: (as far as i know)

1. [Material skin](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin) - Material design for C#
2. [Metro Framework](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework) - adds metro styled controls
3. [LimitlessUI](https://github.com/WithoutCaps/LimitlessUI) - Made by urs truly... small lib that adds simple controls that are easy to work with

Answer (score 0):

[asend.net](http://ascendnet.codeplex.com/) is a nice simple toolkit of controls. And they're all free.